# How can a primary's winner be declared with 0% reporting?

Tags: voting, voting-systems, primaries

The Maryland primary was today. I just did a Google and I'm seeing that Clinton and Trump have been declared winners with 0% reporting.
[image: trump wins Maryland primaries]
 How is that possible? I understand projections but at this point are they going solely off projections or is there real data backing those "winner" declarations?

Answer (score 7):

It's based on pre-election polling, demographics, exit polls, absentee ballots, unofficial voting tabulation, and any other influential political issues. They then use a combination of political science and statistical analysis to make the call.

See: [AP](http://www.ap.org/products-services/elections/calling-races) and 
[CNN](http://www.cnn.com/2010/POLITICS/09/20/projection.explainer/).

Comment: I gave you the tick, but would you mind expanding your answer a little more, by adding a sentence to explain each item (i.e. exit polls - these are surveys that are done as people are exiting the polls, asking them who they voted for) etc.?

Comment: It's kind of hard to expand my answer because the given way an outlet chooses to call the race is ultimately what they think is best.

Comment: Right I'm just asking you explain the different options you listed

Answer (score -2):

If there's zero votes reported, computers may just choose the "default" candidate (frontrunners Trump and Clinton) as the winner and have them win all the delegates.

Comment: [Tonight we divide by zero](https://www.flickr.com/photos/bjepson/3151222824)